# How to return more than two objects from java method to a servlet

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
   public Map<Object, Object> getJiras(String values) throws Exception {       

    {
      ...
       Map<Object, Object> map=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        for(int i=0;i<jsonarr_1.size();i++){
            JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)jsonarr_1.get(i);
            JSONObject jsonobj_2 = (JSONObject)jsonobj_1.get("fields");
            JSONObject status1   = (JSONObject)jsonobj_2.get("status");
            JSONObject issuetype = (JSONObject)jsonobj_2.get("issuetype");
            String var      =  issuetype.get("name").toString();
            System.out.println("\nProject Type: "+var);
            JSONObject email     = (JSONObject)jsonobj_2.get("assignee");
             Object obj3         =  email.get("emailAddress");
            System.out.println(obj3);
            if((var.equals(s2)) || (var.equals(s3)))
            {

            Object obj1         =  jsonobj_1.get("key");
            Object obj2         =  status1.get("name");
            Object obj3         =  email.get("emailAddress");

            map.put(obj1, obj2);
            }
        }
        return  map;
     }
```

Actually I need to return the obj3 to my servlet which calls this getJiras().How can I return it.Please help me with the solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about returning an array? If you necesary need to return a map, you can do something like Map<Object,Object[]>

Comment: You can also create a custom class with as much fields as you need to return, and use it to return the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your `obj3` to the `Map`.

```
map.put("obj3", obj3);
```

now when returned obtain it using,

```
Map<Object, Object> map = getJiras("xxxx");
Object obj3 = map.get("obj3");
```

you may also remove it from the `Map` if necessary, after retrieving it,

```
map.remove("obj3");
```